# c# datagridview - getting advanced pasting functionality

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

if you copy from a webpage an html table and paste it into excel it will be formatted nicely

is it possible to get the same functionality out of datagridview? i want to be able to copy multiple columns of an html table from a webpage and paste it into a datagridview and retain the columns and multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is intercept the paste event triggered by the user and analyze the data to be pasted. If it is a simple value, you can update the cell of the DataGridView with the contents. If it has HTML content, you'll want to parse the contents accordingly.

[This article](http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2007/09/08/datagridview-databound-copy-paste-drag-drop/) has a nice overview on how to extend some of the existing methods to accommodate for this.